# How do I center text with CSS so that one of the elements is always at the center of parent element?

Tags: html, css

I have an element in which I want to show two team names like so: Team1 vs. Team2. However, when the name of one team is considerably longer than the other one, the vs. gets off-centered.

How can I achieve the "vs." part always staying dead-center and having the two elements go right next to it on either sides? All elements are text.

Example:

```
--------Team1-vs.-Team2--------
Team1Longname-vs.-Team2--------
--------Team1-vs.-Team2Longname
```

Comment: Hi, please create example in snippet

Comment: Use a `table` (since that is what this is) and put the "Vs" in the center column

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use flexbox and assign both of the team names `flex: 1`. Then give the team name on the left `text-align: right`

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.wrapper .team {
  flex: 1;
}

.wrapper .vs {
  margin: 0 10px;
}

.wrapper .team:first-child {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <span class="team">Team 1</span>
  <span class="vs">vs.</span>
  <span class="team">Team 2</span>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <span class="team">Team 1</span>
  <span class="vs">vs.</span>
  <span class="team">Team 2 with A Long Name</span>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <span class="team">Team 1 with A Long Name</span>
  <span class="vs">vs.</span>
  <span class="team">Team 2</span>
</div>
```